# Error building OpenCV 3.0.0 rc1 on Windows 7 (64-bit): Cannot compile/link cv2.pyd for Python 3.4

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-3.x, makefile

I am going through some beginner computer vision lessons and I would like to use Python 3.4 instead of 2.7 for the lessons, and I have both versions installed on my computer in `C:/Python34` and `C:/Python27`, respectively. I'm able to `import cv2` into The most recent release of OpenCV, which the lessons require, does support using the cv2 module in Python 3but it has to be built from the source.

To do this, I've used the cmake-gui to create the necessary make files in `c:/opencv`, and I initiate the build by executing `make -j4` in the `c:/opencv/build` directory cmake created. Note that I'm using the mingw32-make command, not visual studios. Both my `gcc` and `g++` compilers work fine; I'm using versions 5.1.0 of both. The full configuration of my generated makefiles is pasted below. I have made a few edits to overcome other compiler errors often encountered.

At present, the build is almost successful (getting to "100%" before failing). The error occurs at the step *Linking CXX shared library ....\lib\cv2.pyd*, `cv2.pyd` being the python library I need to compile in order to import opencv. The full error that stops compilation is this:

`Linking CXX shared library ..\..\lib\cv2.pyd
modules\python3\CMakeFiles\opencv_python3.dir\build.make:215: recipe for target 'lib/cv2.pyd' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:7114: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed`

I've taken a look at the lines specified in the makefiles, but can't see anything that would give me a clue what's going wrong with the linking. I also notice, in the cmake configuration below, that the Python (for build) parameter is set to the pyhon27 executable instead of python34, but haven't been able to find the right parameter to change this, and I'm not certain this is even related to the issue. If anyone has suggestions for how to fix this and make opencv build the pyd for Python 3.4, please chime in.

## CMake configuration

> Detected version of GNU GCC: 51 (501)
>   CUDA compilation is disabled (due to only Visual Studio compiler supported on your platform).
>   Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
>   To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR= option to cmake
>   Found PythonInterp: C:/Python27/python.exe (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
>   Found PythonLibs: C:/Python27/libs/libpython27.a (found suitable exact version "2.7.6") 
>   Found PythonInterp: C:/Python34/python.exe (found suitable version "3.4.2", minimum required is "3.4") 
>   Found PythonLibs: C:/Python34/libs/python34.lib (found suitable exact version "3.4.2") 
>   VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
>    videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default
>
> General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-dev =====================================
>    Version control:               3.0.0-rc1-240-g1df244b-dirty
>
> Platform:
>      Host:                        Windows 6.1 AMD64
>      CMake:                       3.2.2
>      CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
>      CMake build tool:            C:/MinGW/bin/make.exe
>      Configuration:               Release>
>
> C/C++:
>      Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
>      C++ Compiler:                c:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  (ver 5.1.0)
>      C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
>      C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
>      C Compiler:                  c:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
>      C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
>      C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
>      Linker flags (Release):
>      Linker flags (Debug):
>      Precompiled headers:         YES
>      Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 avifil32 avicap32 winmm msvfw32
>      3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf>
>
> OpenCV modules:
>      To be built:                 hal core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab python3
>      Disabled:                    python2 world
>      Disabled by dependency:      -
>      Unavailable:                 androidcamera cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java viz
>
> Windows RT support:            NO
>
> GUI: 
>      QT:                          NO
>      Win32 UI:                    YES
>      OpenGL support:              NO
>      VTK support:                 NO
>
> Media I/O: 
>      ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
>      JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
>      WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
>      PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
>      TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
>      JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
>      OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
>      GDAL:                        NO
>
> Video I/O:
>      Video for Windows:           YES
>      DC1394 1.x:                  NO
>      DC1394 2.x:                  NO
>      FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
>        codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
>        format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
>        util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
>        swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
>        resample:                  NO
>        gentoo-style:              YES
>      OpenNI:                      NO
>      OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
>      OpenNI2:                     NO
>      PvAPI:                       NO
>      GigEVisionSDK:               NO
>      DirectShow:                  YES
>      Media Foundation:            NO
>      XIMEA:                       NO
>      Intel PerC:                  NO
>
> Other third-party libraries:
>      Use IPP:                     NO
>      Use IPP Async:               NO
>      Use Eigen:                   NO
>      Use TBB:                     NO
>      Use OpenMP:                  NO
>      Use GCD                      NO
>      Use Concurrency              NO
>      Use C=:                      NO
>      Use Cuda:                    NO
>      Use OpenCL:                  YES
>
> OpenCL:
>      Version:                     dynamic
>      Include path:                C:/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
>      Use AMDFFT:                  NO
>      Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
>
> Python 2:
>      Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.6)
>
> Python 3:
>      Interpreter:                 C:/Python34/python.exe (ver 3.4.2)
>      Libraries:                   C:/Python34/libs/python34.lib (ver 3.4.2)
>      numpy:                       C:/Python34/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.2)
>      packages path:               C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages
>
> Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe
>
> Java:
>      ant:                         NO
>      JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/include
>      Java wrappers:               NO
>      Java tests:                  NO
>
> Matlab:
>      mex:                         C:/Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/R2009a Student/bin/mex.bat
>      Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)
>
> Documentation:
>      Doxygen:                     NO
>      PlantUML:                    NO
>
> Tests and samples:
>      Tests:                       YES
>      Performance tests:           YES
>      C/C++ Examples:              NO
>
> Install path:                  C:/opencv/build/install
>
> ### cvconfig.h is in:              C:/opencv/build
>
> Configuring done
>   Generating done

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I need to use the python 3 pyd for blender but can't get it to compile. I've been trying for 2 days and can get it to complete ONLY if I tell it I don't want the python 3 module or if I compile in gnu-linux both of which defeat my purpose. They really need to either include the pyd in the download like they do for python 2.7 or fix the plethora of compiling issues.